# PyAudio is clipping the end of sound

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have written/am still playing with a software FSK modem written in python using PyAudio. At first I was modulating the sound into a *.wav file and then playing it at a later time however this is not a long term solution. I have put in place code which takes some given input, prepares the 8N1 data to be sent and then attempts to play it.

My problem is that the sound itself does not seem to play fully; I have verified this by noting that the demodulator produces the correct message sans the last few characters. Recording the wave output by the modulator also corroborates this observation.

I think that the problem has something to do with the frames_per_buffer however I don't know what is going on. I have tried to appeal to PyAudio itself by just sending all the data at once (in a stream.write(...)) however this fails. I have also tried sending it a chunk at a time (as in the case of http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/). I am not, however, playing from a file, rather from an array of samples.

What could the problem be?